# Knockout js 'article' preview box

Tags: knockout.js, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Recently picked up knockoutjs and I'm trying to make a preview box that will render html in a div as I write it inside a wysiwyg editor. Right now I'm trying to get the text I write to render in a div, but it seems to be conflicting with the wysiwyg editor. I tested the script by rendering text written in a normal `<textarea>` field, no problems, worked. However it doesn't render anything when I try to do the same in the wysiwyg editor.

I'm using CKeditor btw. and I basically have this:

```
<textarea name="body" data-bind="value: body"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.replace('body');
</script>
```

Ckeditor needs a `<textarea>` field called 'body' by default which will get replaced with the editors interface.

The script itself works as I mentioned, it works on a normal `<textarea>`, but it seems to not like it when I run `CKEDITOR.replace` on `<textarea>`.

Comment: Use firebug or chrome developer tools to see what the HTML looks like that CKeditor produces. It may be replacing the textarea with some other elements.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that the ckeditor replaces it with contenteditable and there is no value binding it knows about. You can write a customBindingHandler to do this. I wrote one for CLEditor a while ago. Here is what it looks like

```
ko.bindingHandlers.cleditor = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)             {

    var modelValue = valueAccessor();
    var options = {}

    if (allBindingsAccessor().cleditorOptions)
        options = $.extend(options, allBindingsAccessor().cleditorOptions);

    var ko_editor = $(element).cleditor(options);

    if (allBindingsAccessor().cleditorCSS) {
        var cssLink = ko_editor[0].doc.createElement("link");
        cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
        cssLink.type = "text/css";
        cssLink.href = allBindingsAccessor().cleditorCSS;
        if (ko_editor[0].doc.head === undefined) {
            var headElement = ko_editor[0].doc.getElementsByTagName('head');
            headElement[0].appendChild(cssLink);
        }
        else
            ko_editor[0].doc.head.appendChild(cssLink);
    }

    ko_editor[0].change(
        function (a) {
            var elementValue = ko_editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML;

            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                modelValue(elementValue);
            }
            else { //handle non-observable one-way binding
                var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
                if (allBindings['_ko_property_writers'] && allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].htmlValue) allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].htmlValue(elementValue);
            }
        }
      );

},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || "";
    var ko_editor = $(element).cleditor();
    if (ko_editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML !== value) {
        ko_editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML = value;
        ko_editor[0].focus();
    }
}
};
```

and the html will look like this

```
<textarea rows="20" data-bind="cleditor: Body, cleditorCSS: 'path/ComposeEditor.css', cleditorOptions:$root.EditorOptions"></textarea>
```

so you can now provide an observable called Body (which is where the value will be store), a css and options specified in your viewmodel.

Hope that helps you.